# DataFrame/Seriesの欠損値を定数で補完するとき、内挿のみに指定したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

DataFrame/Seriesの欠損値を、定数で補完したいのですが、内挿[limit_area='inside']を指定する方法ありますでしょうか？
両端の欠損値はそのまま補完しないようにしたいです。

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(data=[ None, 20, None, 40, None ], index=[ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee' ], name='value')
print('◇元データ')
display(series.to_frame())

# series = series.fillna(0, limit_area='inside') # ←series.interpolate()と同様にinsideオプションを指定したい。
print('◇↓期待する欠損値補間結果（定数で内挿入したい。外挿したくない。）')
series = pd.Series(data=[ None, 20, 0, 40, None ], index=[ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee' ], name='value')
display(series.to_frame())
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

回答ありがとうございます。
first_valid_index/last_valid_indexメソッドで解決できました。

```
################################################################################
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(
    # data=[ None, None, None, None, None, None ],
    data=[ None, None, 20, None, 40, None ],
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/10'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/11'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/12'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/13'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/14'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/15')
    ], name='value'
)
print('◇元データ')
display(series.to_frame())

index_low = series.first_valid_index()
index_high = series.last_valid_index()
if index_low is not None:
    series.loc[index_low:index_high] = series.loc[index_low:index_high].fillna(0)
display(series.to_frame())
```

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございます。
両端の欠損値がいくつ続くか分からない場合は、どうするべきでしょうか。
質問内容が不明確ですいませんでした。

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(
    data=[ None, None, 20, None, 40, None ],
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/10'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/11'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/12'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/13'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/14'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022/01/15')
    ], name='value'
)
print('◇元データ')
display(series.to_frame())
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問者とは別アカウントのようですが、もし本人であれば追加情報は質問に追記してください。また、アカウントが二つに分かれている件については以下のマニュアルも参考にアカウントの統合を検討してください。[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: [NaN でない値のインデックスを取得する](https://pystyle.info/pandas-check-missing-values/#outline__5) が使えるのでは？

Comment: アカウントはマージ依頼中です。

Comment: @kunif 氏のリンク先に答えがあるのでコメントで。`series[series.first_valid_index():series.last_valid_index()].fillna(0, inplace=True)`